# Python convert value include into a dataframe as a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm still stuck on a transformation issue.

My goals is to convert rows included into a dataframe in a new dataframe

```
df0 = {'Table':['BKPF','BKPF','BKPF','BSEG','BSEG'],
'Zone':['TCODE', 'BLDAT', 'BLART','HKONT','GSBER'],
'Type':['CHAR','DATE','CHAR','CHAR','CHAR'],
'Len' :[10,8,2,10,4]}
```

into 2 new dataframes as

[image]

I'm new in Python, I have tried by different process like:

```
    df0 = pd.read_csv(Ztable, sep=';')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df0)
t_bkpf = df1.loc[df1['Table'] == 'BBKPF']
t_bseg = df1.loc[df1['Table'] == 'BBSEG']
```

or with

```
t_bkpf = pd.DataFrame()
t_bseg = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['Table'] == 'BKPF':
        t_bkpf[row['Zone']] = np.nan

    if row['Table'] == 'BSEG':
        t_bseg[row['Zone']]= np.nan


df_bkpf = t_bkpf.copy()
df_bseg = t_bseg.copy()
```

The result based on code above it the best I have done but I have warning message on performance, I would like avoid it.

On next topic, I need to move data from one other Dataframe to these Dataframe based on columns defined.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df0)
t = df1.set_index('Table')
dfs = [t.loc[idx].pivot(columns='Zone').stack().T for idx in t.index.unique()]
```

First dataframe:

print(dfs[0]):

```
Table  BKPF            
Zone  BLART BLDAT TCODE
Type   CHAR  DATE  CHAR
Len       2     8    10
```

Second dataframe:

print(dfs[1]):

```
Table  BSEG      
Zone  GSBER HKONT
Type   CHAR  CHAR
Len       4    10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df0_dict, orient='index')
df
```

| index | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Table | BKPF | BKPF | BKPF | BSEG | BSEG |
| Zone | TCODE | BLDAT | BLART | HKONT | GSBER |
| Type | CHAR | DATE | CHAR | CHAR | CHAR |
| Len | 10 | 8 | 2 | 10 | 4 |

```
rows = ['Zone', 'Type', 'Len']
df_BKPF = df.loc[rows, df.loc['Table'] == 'BKPF']
df_BKPF
```

| index | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Zone | TCODE | BLDAT | BLART |
| Type | CHAR | DATE | CHAR |
| Len | 10 | 8 | 2 |

```
df_BSEG = df.loc[rows, df.loc['Table'] == 'BSEG']
df_BSEG
```

| index | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Zone | HKONT | GSBER |
| Type | CHAR | CHAR |
| Len | 10 | 4 |